# Could not load file or assembly with specific version missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dependencies, clr, assemblies

In my solution I have a third-party **A.dll** with another **B.dll(Specific version = true)** dependency. But I have older version of B.dll and it goes with error:

Could not load file or assembly 'B, Version=2.0.0.1, ...'

but i have B.dll with little older version (2.0.0.0)

so how can i solve my problem? 
How to loose version depenceny?
 Force to look for older in not exists?

AND what is important A and B are third-party. So i can't change it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just define a version redirection in your app.config.

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19(v=vs.110).aspx).

Or you can set the 'Specific version' option to false.

Of course, both options only work as long as there is no breaking change...

Comment: could u add an example with A and B dlls?

Comment: Just look at the linked page. There is a full example.